# How to let user continue using UWP app after trial expires

Tags: uwp, windows-store

I have an app with a trial period. When the period expires, I detect this in the app using `StoreAppLicense` and I limit features until the full version is purchased. This works great on my development machine.

However, on a test machine, I cannot open the app after the trial expires. Windows pops up a message saying that the trial has expired and that's it.

This is not what I want. I would rather people continue using the app but with some features disabled or with nagging messages to purchase full version. If they cannot open the app, users will lose any incentive to ever buy it, they will just switch to something else!

So, what I want is a time-limited trial with full features. After trial expires, continue with limited features and nags. This is quite common. For example Spotify uses this approach. Free honeymoon period with premium features, after that free version with annoying ads.

Is there a way to implement this in Windows store?

If there's no option to allow expired trial apps to start, I could implement it myself, but I would need "license create date" from the store API. Is there a way to obtain this?

`StoreAppLicense` has `ExpirationDate`, but that is not useful for an unlimited time trial. There does not seem to be a license "start date".

Found `StoreCollectionData.AcquiredDate` in documentation which seems promising, but don't know how to use populate `StoreCollectionData`. Also, not sure if that is install date or first installed date.

Answer (score 0):

> How to let user continue using UWP app after trial expires

Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/exclude-or-limit-features-in-a-trial-version-of-your-app),

> Trial license expires before the app is launched. If the trial expires before the user launches the app, your app won't launch. Instead, users see a dialog box that gives them the option to purchase your app from the Store.

The behavior is by-design. The better way is be sure to explain how your app will behave during and after the free trial period so your customers won't be surprised by your app's behavior.
For more info about describing your app, see [Create app descriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/create-app-store-listings).

**Update**

I think you could set your trial version ExpirationDate as no limit that could make your customer use limit features version all the time, and you could tell user with a prompt for buying the app, and if the customer buys it, continue with all features enabled. If the user decides not to buy the app, close it or remind them to buy the app at regular.intervals

And you could also set the customer stopwatch in your app( base on no limit trial time version).If the app expires, it will prompt the user to restrict the use of some functions. if the customer purchased, you could disable stopwatch.

Comment: I understand this is by design. I'm looking for ways around it. Is there a way to get license acquired date from the store?

Comment: I think you could set your trial  version ExpirationDate no limit that could make your customer use limit features version all the time, and you could tell user with a prompt for buying the app, and if the customer buys it, continue with all features enabled. If the user decides not to buy the app, close it or remind them to buy the app at regular.intervals

Comment: @under You could get acquired date with `ExpirationDate` - `Trial Period`.

Comment: Zhu, expiration date is year 9999. I need a start date so I can work out my own trial period... Also, store allows a maximum of 30 days for trials. Can they not allow user to specify a value? I could run a 2 year trial and start nagging people to upgrade after a month. But the way it is now, there does not seem to be a way to implement a customized trial period.

Comment: Can I use this to get something useful from the store API like trial start date? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storerequesthelper.sendrequestasync?view=winrt-19041

Comment: Why you want to get trial start date, and have you checked  [TrialTimeRemaining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeapplicense.trialtimeremaining?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Services_Store_StoreAppLicense_TrialTimeRemaining) property that comes from `StoreAppLicense`  class

Comment: Trial time remaining returns thousands of years. It is completely useless. I have changed the setting in the store to "unlimited" to prevent the store from locking users out of the app. I need a start date so I can work out whether the user is in the "honeymoon" period (first month, no nagging), or if I need to start asking for payment.

Comment: Ok, I got it, for this scenario, we suggest set your app as free , and make two add-ons  for this app,  one is 30 days free subscription add-on, and other is paid add-on . when user lunched app please guide for 30 days subscription add-on.  when the subscription add-on has expired, please tell the user for the complete function please purchase.

Comment: Your answer does not really answer my question. Your comment about using add-ons (Oct 23) comes close, but this is complicated for the user, and I really don't want that. The easiest and most flexible solution is for MS Store API to return license "start date". Why can't we have this? Can you not pull some strings in MS to give developers this? :-) Or are they giving up on the store as some people are saying? :-(